# DRF serializer return nullable fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In a drf serializer, if a value is not in the post data, how do I still keep the field name with a null value?

I'm using version 3.3.3

```
TYPES = [
    ("abc", "abc"),
    ("def", "def"),
]

class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    choice = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=TYPES, required=False, initial=None)

serializer = MySerializer(data={})
serializer.is_valid()
print serializer.data
```

Current output is `{}`

Desired output is `{'choice': None}`

Comment: Shouldn't `required` be `False` then?

Comment: Sorry typo in my example but still produces the same output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this it should return what you expect

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    choice = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=TYPES, required=False, allow_blank=True)
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        if 'choice' in ret:
           return ret
        else:
            ret.update({'choice':''})
            return ret
```

check the documentation to get what to_representation do
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#to_representationself-obj